# Looking for console program to generate tones

Tags: software-recommendation, console, music-player

I've been googling for a while now and I can't find what I am looking for.

I'm in the need of a console program that can play notes.

Example:

play C C D D E E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `play` command from the `sox` package, e.g.

```
for note in C C D D E E; 
do 
    play -n -c1 synth 1 sine $note;
done
```

which plays a 1-second sine wave for each of the notes in turn.

The man page for `sox` provides all of the options that can be used with the `synth` effect. It is very powerful if not the most user-friendly way to generate audio.

Comment: perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!